# How to emit events from Node-Red to a Unity client with node-red-contrib-socketio

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, socket.io, node-red

I'm trying to use node-red-contrib-socketio package to emit a 'weather' event from Node-Red to a client based on input from Weather Underground.

[image: Emit Weather Event from Node-Red]

I'm using the following code in a node-red function to process the input from WeatherUnderground and set the event:

[image: Setting 'weather' event]

```
weather = msg.payload.weather;
msg.payload = {weather: weather};
msg.socketIOEvent = 'weather';
RED.util.setMessageProperty(msg, "socketIOEmit", "emit", true);
return msg;
```

Is this the correct way to set and emit the weather event?

For reference:

I've bound the SocketIO Out node to Node_Red (so presumably port 1880 on local host). I'm using the Unity game engine as the client to receive the event with the Socket.IO library from the asset store: https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/socket-io-for-unity-21721

Unity is listening for the weather event on the following URL:

```
ws://127.0.0.1:1880/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=websocket
```

Currently Unity seems to be registering the connection but not the emitted weather event.

My test C# script for handling the events in Unity is as follows:

```
using UnityEngine;
using SocketIO;

public class NodeNetwork : MonoBehaviour
{

    //Reference socket component
    static SocketIOComponent socket;

    void Start()
    {
        //Initialise reference to socket component
        socket = GetComponent<SocketIOComponent>();
        //Register callbacks for network events
        socket.On("open", OnConnected);
        socket.On("weather", OnWeather);
    }

    //Create a callback for the connection
    void OnConnected(SocketIOEvent e)
    {
        Debug.Log("Connected");
        //Emit a move call back to the server 
        socket.Emit("client connected");
    }

    //Create a callback for receipt of weather events
    void OnWeather(SocketIOEvent e)
    {
        Debug.Log("New weather event received" + e.data);
        socket.Emit("weather received");
    }

}
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: By any chance, is `socket.On("weather", OnWeather);` not fired before you established connection correctly ?

Comment: Where if you get the code in the function node from? There is no need for the `RED.util.setMessageProperty()` it can be replaced by `msg.socketIOEmit = "emit";`

Comment: @hardillb The code was derived from the example chat app provided for the node. That line was actually causing me errors but I was trying to work out what it was doing but I tried to work with it. I'll ditch it and see where I get. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Hi I tried replacing `RED.util.setMessageProperty()` with `msg.socketIOEmit = "emit"` as suggested. This has the same effect on the output in the debugger. Either way I get the error `"TypeError: Cannot read property 'broadcast' of undefined"`. Removing that line altogether allows me to send the payload to Unity successfully (the default on the node is to broadcast to all). However, this leaves me unsure how to set the emit property in Node-Red to target the client rather than broadcasting to all. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further research and testing I got this working. The Node-Red flow was fine but some sort of configuration issue prevented it working. Reinstalling Node.js and Node-Red resolved the issue.

Using `msg.socketIOEmit = "emit"` as advised by @hardillb works.

I tested several SocketIO solutions for Unity and ended using [SocketIO for Native and WebGL builds by DASPETE](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/socketio-for-native-and-webgl-builds-76508) which is a $10 paid asset.

In order to deserialise the JSON I used SaladLab's [JSONNetLite Unity package](https://github.com/SaladLab/Json.Net.Unity3D/releases) which is a fork of NewtonSoft.JSon.NET.

To successfully use the package in a Unity WebGL build you need to add a [link.xml file](https://github.com/SaladLab/Json.Net.Unity3D/blob/master/src/UnityPackage/Assets/link.xml) to your assets folder. This adds exceptions to the default Unity bytecode stripping which removes unused code from DLL's like the Newtonsoft.Json package.

I hope that helps if you have the same issues.

Answer (score 1):

From the code you provided and the owner of the asset it seems to be the [DEPRECATED SocketIO Unity port](https://github.com/fpanettieri/unity-socket.io-DEPRECATED), I'd advise you to look into [socket.io-unity](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/socket.io-unity) (which is free from github and 10$ from the asset store) which is a revised version of Quobject's [SocketIoClientDotNet](https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet) to work with Unity3D

I know this is not a concrete answer (apart from switching library) to fixing your problem, but the owner of your package has said himself over 2 years ago now that he had stopped development of it. Hence why I think it would be interesting to switch library as primary option, I actually think you did things right, and it just doesn't work. I'm currently at work and can't test this out, sorry. I hope I was able to help in some way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Antry. The asset I was using still works fine for me with Node.js but moving to a supported library is probably a good move. Hopefully it will work for WebGL builds too.

Comment: Hi @Antry, I thought you might want to know that there are currently a range of issues with socket.io-unity as outlined here: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/socket.io-unity/issues/1 I'm getting a conflict with the Unity post-processing stack. Going to try an alternative solution.

Comment: @VirtualArchitectures Ay, that sucks, hope they will fix this, have you found any workaround or alternative ?

Comment: Hey @Antry, thanks for the follow up. Apparently you can workaround the issue with the floatinghotpot asset by editing the source code and rebuilding. For a quick solution I opted for using the [SocketIO for Native and WebGL builds by DASPETE](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/network/socketio-for-native-and-webgl-builds-76508).

Comment: @VirtualArchitectures Well yeah, he should be able to edit or specify the used namespace on his declarations and there wouldn't be any more problem, idk why he has not done that. Congratz on the solution, too bad it is a proprietary/paid solution though. I hope you achieve what you are aiming for.